# Can't override onCreateDialog method of androidx.fragment.app.Dialog

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

When I try to override the `onCreateDialog` method of `androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment` I get the following error: 'onCreateDialog overrides nothing'.

According to [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/fragment/app/DialogFragment) I should be able to override it as it's defined as open.

I am using the following code

```
import android.app.AlertDialog
import android.app.Dialog
import android.content.DialogInterface
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment


class MyDialogFragment : DialogFragment() {

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle): Dialog {
        return activity?.let {
            val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(it)
            builder.setMessage("Yes or no?")
                .setPositiveButton("yes",
                    DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialog, id ->
                        // yes
                    })
                .setNegativeButton("no",
                    DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialog, id ->
                        // no
                    })
            builder.create()
        } ?: throw IllegalStateException("Activity cannot be null")
    }
}
```

What's going on here?

Comment: perhaps `savedInstanceState` should be of type `Bundle?`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you look closely at the method signature you will see that the parameter is marked with the `@Nullable`, and its type is `Bundle?`.

```
onCreateDialog(@Nullable savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
```

But in your case you have defined the type of parameter as `Bundle` which is non nullable, making your function signature different than the one you are trying to override hence the error

Answer (score 3):

Change `savedInstanceState: Bundle` to `savedInstanceState: Bundle?`